# android AudioTrack setloop invalid value

Tags: android, audiotrack

I generate a PCM and want to loop the sound.
I follow the documentation, but Eclipse keep telling me that

```
08-05 15:46:26.675: E/AudioTrack(27686): setLoop invalid value: loopStart 0, loopEnd 44100, loopCount -1, framecount 11025, user 11025
```

here is my code:

```
void genTone() {
    // fill out the array
    for (int i = 1; i < numSamples - 1; i = i + 2) {
        sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / -300));
    }

    // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
    // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
    int idx = 0;
    for (double dVal : sample) {
        short val = (short) (dVal * 32767);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }

    //write it to audio Track.
    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples);
    audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, numSamples, -1); 
    //from 0.0 ~ 1.0
    audioTrack.setStereoVolume((float)0.5, (float)1); //change amplitude
}



public void buttonPlay(View v) {
    audioTrack.reloadStaticData();
    audioTrack.play();
}
```

please help ~~

Comment: sorry guys. I just found a great post here=.=
http://bin-liu.blogspot.dk/2011/12/looping-audio-file-via-audiotrack.html
just divide the numSamples few times, it will start working. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setLoopPoints%28int,%20int,%20int%29): "`endInFrames` loop end marker expressed in *frames*"

The log print indicates that your track contains 11025 frames, which is less than the 44100 that you're trying to specify as the end marker (for 16-bit stereo PCM audio, the frame size would be 4 bytes).

Another thing worth noting is that "the track must be stopped or paused for the position to be changed".